# Set ZipArchiveEntry.CompressionLevel to CompressionLevel.NoCompression not work in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to create a zip archive for store files and set `ZipArchiveEntry.CompressionLevel` to `CompressionLevel.NoCompression`,
but when I run my android apk in release mode, all ZipArchiveEntries compressed and have ratio >0%.
I use xamarin for android 4.1.1.3 and test the apk in lenovo tab 4 A7-30GC and asus Z00VD.
sample code:

```
 public void AddToArchive(string EntryName, string Path, DateTime TimeStamp)
    {
        ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = this.Archive.CreateEntry(EntryName, CompressionLevel.NoCompression);
        zipEntry.LastWriteTime = TimeStamp;
        using (Stream entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
        {
            using (Stream fileStream = File.Open(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            entryStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based upon the Microsoft .Net reference source (via the Mono source), setting `CompressionLevel` only provides a "hint" to the underlaying compression code.

You will see that some files when compressed at the "zero" compression level end up seeing some compression due to file optimizations that are done regardless of the compression level requested. This is will be found across Mono, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, .Net, etc...

> This is an abstract concept and NOT the ZLib compression level.
>   There may or may not be any correspondance with the a possible implementation-specific level-parameter of the deflater.

```
///------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <copyright file="CompressionLevel.cs" company="Microsoft">
///     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
/// </copyright>                               
///
/// <owner>gpaperin</owner>
///------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This is an abstract concept and NOT the ZLib compression level.
// There may or may not be any correspondance with the a possible implementation-specific level-parameter of the deflater.
public enum CompressionLevel {
    Optimal = 0,
    Fastest = 1,
    NoCompression = 2
}
```